# JWPlayer not showing up for Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwplayer

I would like to use JWPlayer to showcase video/audio stored on my webserver. I have downloaded the JWPlayer installation zip file (includes 2 .js files and 1 .swf)

I have put the .js files under assets/javascript/jwplayer/*.js

In my application.html.erb I have

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "/assets/jwplayer" %>
```

Unfortunately upon load I get *jwplayer is not defined* error on the jwplayer.html5.js (line 1).

Is that because of the .swf file? I have put that under the assets/ directory.

Comment: Version 6 of JWPlayer expects all three files to be on the same directory. Could you post the generated html code?

Comment: Having a similar issue here. I have all the files on the same directory. I will post another question as the comment section does not allow me to post it properly with legible code

Comment: Follow the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825970/jw-player-and-rails-3-2/16817568#16817568

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the jwplayer-rails gem. I am still waiting on my pull request to go through. For now follow the info in [this](https://github.com/dutgriff/jwplayer-rails/blob/master/README.md) readme to get it up and running. Read more on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825970).